# Modal Form Within Modal Form Issue

Tags: c#, modal-dialog

One button in my Main Form does the following:

```
 private void buttonGabarito_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            FormGabarito fg = (FormGabarito)Application.OpenForms["FormGabarito"];

            if (fg == null)
            {
               fg = new FormGabarito(this);
            }

            fg.ShowDialog();
        }
```

Then, in my "FormGabarito" theres a "saveButton"

```
    private void buttonExport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var fb = new SaveFileDialog();
        fb.Filter = "xml file (*.xml) | *.xml";
        var res = fb.ShowDialog();

        if (fb.FileName != null)
        {
            Manager.DtGabarito.WriteXml(fb.FileName);
            UpdateAll();
        }
    }
```

And my issue is: when I close the SaveFileDialog, either by selecting a path or clicking in cancel, my FormGabarito is closed too! And my Main Form, lol.

I added the following line

```
this.DialogResult = DialogResult.None;
```

after

```
var res = fb.ShowDialog();
```

Now this issue only happens when I click the cancel button in the SaveFileDialog.
Why is this happening? How can I fix it

Answer (score 0):

I tried to recreate the issue with similar code and it works without error.

My guess is it must be causing error(permission or something) with following code,

```
//Manager.DtGabarito.WriteXml(fb.FileName);
//UpdateAll();
```

Working Code:

```
   public partial class Form1 : Form
   {
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 fg = (Form2)Application.OpenForms["Form2"];

        if (fg == null)
        {
            fg = new Form2();
        }

        fg.ShowDialog();
    }
  }



 public partial class Form2 : Form
 {

    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }      

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var fb = new SaveFileDialog();
        fb.Filter = "xml file (*.xml) | *.xml";
        var res = fb.ShowDialog();            
        if (fb.FileName != null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(fb.FileName);
            //Manager.DtGabarito.WriteXml(fb.FileName);
            //UpdateAll();
        }
    }       
}
```